# When running a Polly Policy in a .NET Core application, it hangs after the exception is caught

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, polly

I'm trying to test out some Polly "retry" code I have in a basic .NET Core application. I have to implement an async method (via the inherited Interface):

```
public Task AddMessageAsync( ... ) { .. }
```

Notice how the method above is NOT decorated with the `async` keyword? I did that on purpose.

When I try and connect to the 3rd party service (a RabbitMQ server) where I've made hostname of this service, incorrect/typo'd, my sync code tries and fails and throws an exception. Great! but after that, the code just hangs? I thought that the code should just keep retrying.

```
private static Policy CheckRabbitMQPolicy(ILogger logger)
{
    return Policy
        .Handle<Exception>()
        .WaitAndRetry(15, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), (exception, timeSpan, __) => logger.LogWarning(...));
}

public Task AddMessageAsync(string content,
                            TimeSpan? timeToLive,
                            TimeSpan? initialVisibilityDelay,
                            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    CheckRabbitMQPolicy(_logger).Execute(() =>
    {
        using (var connection = _factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            .... // snipped //
        }
    });

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

So I thought that I could just return a `Task.CompletedTask;` because there is no code called in this method that is `async/await`. But when the exception is thrown, it's handled (the `log.Warning(..)` is called / breaked-on if there's a breakpoint there), but then hangs.

How can I debug what's going on here?

### Edit

As per @jeremy-thompson 's reply below, I thought I might try changing the code to:

```
var policyResult = CheckRabbitMQPolicy(_logger).ExecuteAndCapture(() =>
{
    using (var connection = _factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        .... // snipped //
    }
});


return policyResult.Outcome == OutcomeType.Successful
    ? Task.CompletedTask
    : Task.FromException(policyResult.FinalException);
```

So this then:

- tries to connect to the bad-server
- fails and throws the exception
- exits the ExecuteAndCapture() now (doesn't return 14 more times...)
- returns `Task.FromException` ...

This is a little bit closer, but still doesn't keep retrying 14 more times.

Comment: Is it this issue: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/106

Comment: @JeremyThompson updated OP :)  Thanks _heaps_ for the help/reply, btw.

Comment: We would need a minimum, complete verifiable example. For instance, we can't see (from q as posted) how `AddMessageAsync(...)` is called. Mixing sync/async code in certain ways (especially any uses of `.Wait()`) is the usual cause of hangs in these situations.  If you can put a breakpoint on the `return` statement within `AddMessageAsync(...)`, and hit that breakpoint, before the hang occurs, then nothing within `AddMessageAsync(...)` is implicated; the issue may be to do with how you handle the return value of `AddMessageAsync(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You should always try to present a minimum working example in the question that demonstrates the problem you're facing. I took your code and tried to make it a running example but everything seems to work as expected. It reties 14 times and it doesn't hang as you describe.

Perhaps by simplifying your code in a similar way you can figure out what's wrong in your case. Good luck!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var msg = new MyMessageClass();
        msg.AddMessageAsync("content", TimeSpan.MaxValue, TimeSpan.MaxValue, new CancellationToken());
    }
}

class MyMessageClass
{
    readonly ILogger _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private static Policy CheckRabbitMQPolicy(ILogger logger)
    {
        return Policy
            .Handle<Exception>()
            .WaitAndRetry(14, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                (exception, timeSpan, __) =>
                {
                    logger.Warn(exception.Message);
                });
    }
    public Task AddMessageAsync(string content,
        TimeSpan? timeToLive,
        TimeSpan? initialVisibilityDelay,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var policyResult = CheckRabbitMQPolicy(_logger).ExecuteAndCapture(() => throw new Exception("Connection error"));

        return policyResult.Outcome == OutcomeType.Successful
            ? Task.CompletedTask
            : Task.FromException(policyResult.FinalException);
    }
}
```